# VBA excel code:cannot give named range to formula1 in validation

Tags: validation, vba, excel

How can i add a validation list by vba code that will refer to a named range?
So that the list will contain the values of a named range?
I can do this like Formula1:="=$A$1:$A$10" but how can i give a named range?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following code:

```
'Create the named range (if not done already)
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="listdata", RefersTo:= "=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10" 
'Set a validation list on the cells that will refer to the named range
With Range("A1:A100") 
    With .Validation 
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _ 
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=listdata" 
    End With 
End With
```

Comment: @Michelle: if this answer fits you, please don't forget to accept it --> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more information