# Maximum drop-down list/formula length in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

I have the following VBA code:

```vb
myList = "test"

Range("A1:Z1").Validation.Delete
Range("A1:Z1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
```

If my list exceeds 256 characters, it is truncated. If it exceeds 1024, I get an execution error (I think it is the maximum length for a formula).

How can I get over those limits? I'm using Excel 2003.

Comment: Perhaps try a different approach rather than the built in Excel Validation. I've used this with success: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal11.html. It does take a bit of work to set up, but I think it'll do what you're after.

Comment: I have to create **everything** dynamically. The macro is set as a reference and edits the first line of any opened document. Not sure if I can create a combobox control in every cells dynamically.

Comment: You can use the Named Range approach from the link http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal11.html What you can do (and i do this) is to create a hidden sheet and in that sheet I populate say Col A with my list and give it a name and then use that named range in the datavalidation list. Give it a try and if you get stuck then simply post the code that you tried post which I can show you an example code on how to achieve it. :)

Comment: As I've already said below, the VBA project is set as a reference and is used and many Excel documents. I looked at that approach but I would have to create dynamically the names and then the controls. It looks like a little bit more complex.

Comment: No you do not need to create the controls ;) Just the named range in the hidden sheet

Comment: But I can't do `ComboxBox.ListFillRange = str` if I have no ComboBox, right? Cells don't have the `ListFillRange` property. That's the only thing missing here, something to replace the `Range.Validation` I'm actually using.

Comment: But that is my point... you do not need to create a combobox... you can directly use the named range in your drop down list (which is also called Data Validation List)

Comment: It works after some more searches. This link was also useful: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52916

Comment: Yup that link shows you what exactly I was referring to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the link posted in the comments above, I was able to create a dropdown list with more than 256/1024 chars. Here's what I managed to get after some more searches and tries:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="List", RefersTo:="=ValidationList!$A$1:$A$" & i
Range("A1:AZ1").Validation.Delete
Range("A1:AZ1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=List"
```

Nothing more than this. `i` is the number of lines of *ValidationList* sheet. I'm creating that sheet dynamically and populating the first A column with what I want to show up in the dropdown list.

Useful references:

- http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal11.html
- http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52916
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839847.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/830b42cf-8c97-4aaf-b34b-d860773281f7/
- [VBA excel code:cannot give named range to formula1 in validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786540/vba-excel-codecannot-give-named-range-to-formula1-in-validation)