# Error in Size array VBA

Tags: vba

I'm again 
exist a error when i use array

The maximum size that admits me from the array is 26
Why is this happening?

the error is in
Module 3
function listbox
in this line

```
Dim mylist1(26) As String
For i = 0 To 26
    mylist1(i) = CStr(Worksheets("Helper").Cells(i + 6, 4).Value)
Next i
With ws.Range("E8:E8").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(mylist1, ",")
End With
```

I get values from a hidden sheet
if change the size to 27 have error after save
if you change to 27 save
and open again, has a error

this is file link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Uaop86I2AKpeOwORrKYUafGb67b214Bh

thanks

Comment: "I have an error" is not a valid description of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum drop-down list/formula length in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16017403/11683)

Comment: is length from array, not characters (sorry), but i dont understan why happening

Comment: Do you realize that `Join` creates a single string?

Comment: a single??
but I get a list of 26 words
not a list of 1 word , I need to make any change?

Comment: When you call `Join(mylist1, ",")`, what do you expect it to produce if not a single string that contains all your 26 values separated with commas? If you don't expect that to happen, then why do you call `Join`, and if you do expect it to happen, then why do you wonder that it happens? You create a string from your array, that strings ends up being too long when you add 27th element to the array.

Comment: Can you say exactly which line has the error? What does the error message say? Where do you assign the variable ws to a worksheet?

Comment: @Luis - further to what Absinthe asked you - you said `if change the size to 27 have error after save`.  **Show us.**  Please [edit] your question to add a **screen shot of your code when it says "27"** *and* a **screen shot of the error you are seeing.**  Without this we are only guessing about your problem and we cannot help you.

Comment: @LuisAguilar - Also, if you feel that language is a barrier in getting your point across, have you tried [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the error is likely to be thrown out of too long a string, then you can turn your validation formula to reference the list range and get rid of `mylist1` array:

```
Dim nElements As Long

nElements = 26
With WS.Range("E8").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Helper!$D$6:$D$" & 6 + nElements-1
End With
```

Comment: nice approach. Will remember that.

Comment: @LuisAguilar, you are welcome. if my answer solved your question then please consider marking it as accepted. thank you