# Excel VBA - Passing Correct Arguments to Procedures

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have been at this since yesterday but cannot seem to find my way.

In the below procedure, I create the obj. dropdownRange to be passed as argument to the procedure at the bottom. However, both of the arguments output empty in the 'immediate window' when I debug.print them.

I do not get an error on line -> With curCell.Validation, however, I do get the following error on the next line -> .Add Type...

*Error: 1004 : Application-defined or Object-defined error*

```
    Dim mainTab As Object   'Tab 'main'
    Dim tranTypeSize As Integer 'Length of entries for transaction type
    Dim dropdownRange As Range 'Dynamic range for dropdown
    Set mainTab = Sheets("Main")

        tranTypeSize = Sheets("Misc").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set dropdownRange = Sheets("Misc").Range("A1:A" & tranTypeSize) ' <- problem

    Call createDropdownList(mainTab.Range("G8"), dropdownRange) '<- arguments passed are wrong obj?
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
Sub createDropdownList(ByRef curCell As Range, _
    ByVal targetList As Range)

    With curCell.Validation ' <- I think error, though it passes this line
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=targetList ' <- error
```

*****UPDATE:*****
Further to @ExcelDeveloper's comment, I am trying the following which I think is close but still not working (error: application or object defined error)
Sub createDropdownList(ByRef curCell As Range, _
    ByVal targetList As Range)

```
Dim targetAddress As String
targetAddress = "Misc!" & targetList.Address
                   Debug.Print targetAddress
With curCell.Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=targetAddress
```

Comment: have you tried to use the macro recorder in order to check the code for the `validaton.add` method

Comment: Yes, I recorded, then copied & edited the 'targetList' in as my range

Comment: i found a similar problem on stackoverflow, maybe this can help you too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786540/vba-excel-codecannot-give-named-range-to-formula1-in-validation

Comment: Thank you @psychicebola, that is one way of solving it. I am curious as though why my approach is not working. The error appears to be in the 1st procedure (before they are passed as arguments) I think...

Comment: I assume, that `formula1` requires a single reference, which can lead to a range, or a comma separated list (according to MSDN). But it can't handle a directly given range like you did it.

Comment: I think it should be Formula1:=targetList.Address. If the validation list is on a different sheet then you need the SheetName!Address format.

Comment: if your question is answered, please mark it so.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers Very interestesting. Thanks, this is close, however, now its inserting the range as list in the validation. When I click on the dropdown icon, I get one list item with the value -> $A$1:$A$4

Comment: Formula1 := "=" & targetList.Address

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers Thank you, that did it for me. Would you please post a separate answer so I can choose it as correct. You all have been awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Formula1 property should be the address of the range you are referring to, preceded by an equal sign:

```
 Formula1 := "=" & targetList.Address
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that formula1 requires a single reference, which can lead to a range, or a comma separated list (according to MSDN). But it can't handle a directly given range like you did it.

[give named range to formula1 in validation.add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786540/vba-excel-codecannot-give-named-range-to-formula1-in-validation)

Comment: Thank you Psychicebola, Im trying to do it through the dynamic range route. If that doesnt work, I'll go to named ranges.

Comment: please, don't forget to mark the question as answered (the green tick), if it worked, otherwise let me know and i will edit my answer.